# Mean time for the trajectory. Find mean

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, markov-process

What is the mean of time when the trajectory of the wiener process, $W_t$, is over the line $y=t$?

We need to find $\Bbb{E}\tau$, where $\tau=\sum\limits_{a,b:\forall t\in(a,b)
; W_t>t}\left(b-a\right)$.

By the law of iterated logarithm $P\left(\sup\{t: W_t>t\}<\infty\right)=1$. Then we could find a sequence $t_i$ of points where $W_{t_i}=t_i$.

By local modulus of continuity there is infinite set of such points near $0$.

Then $\tau=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(t_n-t_{n-1}\right)$. How do we find its mean?

Comment: $E\tau = \int_0 ^\infty P(W_x>x)\,dx$.

Comment: You have a very naïve view of the Brownian paths (I suggest to find some simulations on the web and to meditate them). No, the set $\{t\mid W_t>t\}$ is not a locally finite union of intervals. To find $E(\tau)$, note that $$\tau=\int_0^\infty\mathbf 1_{W_t>t}dt,$$ hence $$E(\tau)=\int_0^\infty P(W_t>t)dt.$$ To go further, can you evaluate $P(W_t>t)$ for every $t$? (Amusingly, the final result seems to be $E(\tau)=\frac12$...)

Comment: @Did Why is $E(\tau)$ equal to that integral?

Comment: We should get $\mathbb{E}_{\tau}=\int\limits_{0}^{\infty}P\left(\tau>t\right)dt$, how we we use this?

Comment: "Why is E(τ) equal to that integral?" Because τ is equal to that other integral. "how (do) we use this?" We don't (that is, if we want to find the solution of the exercise relatively painlessly).

Answer (score 1):

We start from
$$\tau=\int_0^\infty\mathbf 1_{W_t\gt t}\,\mathrm dt,\quad \Bbb E(\tau)=\int_0^\infty P(W_t\gt t)\,\mathrm dt$$

Since $W_t$ is normal centered with ariance $t$, $$P(W_t\gt t)=P(\sqrt{t}Z\gt t)=P(Z\gt\sqrt{t})$$ where $Z$ is standard normal.
 By symmetry, $P(Z\lt-\sqrt{t})=P(Z\gt\sqrt{t})$ hence
$$2P(Z\gt\sqrt{t})=P(Z\gt\sqrt{t})+P(Z\lt-\sqrt{t})=P(Z^2\gt t)$$ which gives
$$\Bbb E(\tau)=\frac12\left(\int_0^\infty P(Z^2\gt t)\,\mathrm dt\right)=\frac12 \Bbb E(Z^2)=\frac12$$

We don't need $\mathbb{E}(\tau)=\int\limits_{0}^{\infty}P\left(\tau>t\right)dt$.